# Xcode cannot run using the selected destination

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake

I am building a Mac OS X application and from time to time, I get this error message from Xcode (Version 5.0.1 (5A2034a)):

[image]

However the architecture (i386 or x86_64, it seems to happen on both) is supported by my system (Mac OS X 10.9).

Clicking a second time on the Run button (or press Cmd+r) sometimes fix the problem.

Sometimes I have to delete the application in my build folder and then rebuild it.

Note: I am using cmake to generate the Xcode project.

Answer (score 11):

The same thing just started happening to me.

As was suggested [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2012/Sep/msg00330.html), stopping and starting Xcode cleared the problem.